# Error: Could not find 2 Android X assemblies, make sure to install the following NuGet packages:

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I updated a Xamarin Forms application with the latest version of Xamarin.

Now I get the following error:
Could not find 2 Android X assemblies, make sure to install the following NuGet packages:

- Xamarin.AndroidX.MediaRouter
- Xamarin.AndroidX.Palette

You can also copy-and-paste the following snippet into your .csproj file:

The packages DO exist and are installed for .Android only.
The suggestion to copy-and-paste the snippets into the .csproj file does not work as these packages are not compatible with .NET2.0

I have read a few posts of people experiencing similar issues but have found no solution. Here's what I've tried:

Remove both packages.
Clean solution.
Restart VS
Install packages, for .Android only
Clean Solution
Build Solution ----- Errors with the above message still.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you ever tried to create a new project and then install the NuGet package?

Comment: Hi @LeoZhu-MSFT Thank you for taking the time to help me out. I have not tried that. I'll give it a go and if it works, I'll just copy-paste my code into the new project.